# Ionic 2 - How to remove gap between header and content?

Tags: ionic2

I have an **Ionic 2 side menu** **app**. When I toggle the menu it pops out, and when toggeling it again it disappears but makes a **gap** between the header and the content (on the **left side**).

Does anyone know why this happens ?

Also after doing some interaction on the page (a button click), the gap disappears.

[image]

Comment: I would assume the `no-padding` attribute, found in many elements in Ionic ( like `<ion-content no-padding>` ), but w/o your code - it's a bit of a problem to reproduce your issue.
I would recommend you to use https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

how you are using the menue? can you include your code?
how ever you can close menu function to hide menu without gaps
for Examle:

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public menu: MenuController)
```

`openPage(page) {
    // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
    this.menu.close();
    this.nav.push(page.component);
  }`